# Passing Variable As Markdown

Tags: laravel, markdown

I am trying to use a variable to fill a table in markdown.
I am using Laravel with the package (https://larecipe.binarytorch.com.my/docs/2.2/overview)

Essentially what I want to achieve is to pass an array to fill out a table within my docs files

Standard markdown table looks like this

```
Name             | ID       | Description
:-               |  :       | :-      Name             | ID       | Description
:-               |  :       | :-
```

for the fields I am using Laravel's blade::directives

```
        Blade::directive('ticketTypes', function() {
            $ticketTypes = TicketType::get();

            $table = '';
            $table .= $ticketTypes[0]->name . ' | ' . $ticketTypes[0]->hash_id . ' | ' .  '$'.$ticketTypes[0]->getReadablePrice();

            return $table;
        });
```

Which enables me to use it like so

```
Name             | ID       | Description
:-               |  :       | :-      
@ticketTypes
```

Only issue is my variable is not parsed like a table, it only prints as text

I am quite new to markdown's is there a standard way to parse variable text as a table?

Image for context [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if anybody else does hit this point I managed to go around it by using direct html inside the markdown and generate the html elements within the variable:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            @ticketTypes
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
 foreach ($ticketTypes as $ticketType) {
        $table .= <<<EOT
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            $ticketType->name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $ticketType->hash_id
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            $ticketTypePrice
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                EOT;
    }
```